# ¿Cómo puedo cerrar un formulario de inicio de sesión y mostrar el formulario principal sin que se cierre mi aplicación?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, login, visual-studio-2010

**Detalle:**

Básicamente lo que trato de hacer es que, si el inicio de sesión es exitoso, debo mostrar el formulario principal y cerrar el formulario de inicio de sesión (Esto lo hago perfectamente bien solo la primera vez).

**Problema:**

Mi problema es que en el formulario principal tengo un botón para cerrar sesión, al momento de hacer click quiero que regrese a la pantalla de inicio de sesión. Sin embargo, cuando creo la instancia para abrir el formulario de inicio de sesión, luego de intentar iniciar sesión nuevamente, nunca accedera al formulario principal, ya que este se invoca en el `Program.cs` y no en la el botón iniciar sesión.

Este es mi código actual:

**Método 1:**

**Program.cs:**

```
[STAThread]
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
                
    Login login = new Login();
    DialogResult result = login.ShowDialog();
    if (result == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        Application.Run(new Form_Principal());
    }
    else
    {
        Application.Exit();
    } 
}
```

**Login.cs:**

```
public partial class Login : Form
{
    ///......
    ///......
    private void btnIniciarSesion_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(autenticar()) // un método que devuelve verdadero cuando el usuario y la clave son correctas.
        {             
           this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
           this.Close();
        }
        else
        {
           MessageBox.Show("Datos Incorrectos, reintentar...");
        } 
    }
}
```

**Form_Principal.cs:**

```
public partial class Form_Principal: Form
{
    ///......
    ///......
    private void btnCerrarSesion_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       this.Close();
       Login login = new Login();
       login.Show();
    }
}
```

> De este modo cuando cierro la sesión, y vuelvo a intentar iniciar sesión, nunca abrirá el formulario principal ya que este se invoca en el `Program.cs` asi: `Application.Run(new Form_Principal());` asi que simplemente ejecutará el código: `if(autenticar()){ this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK; this.Close(); }` y simplemente cerará el `Login`.

---

**Método 2:**

Con este método el formulario de inicio de sesión luego que el usuario se autentica, este será ocultado y estará oculto todo el tiempo.

**Program.cs:**

```
[STAThread]
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(new Login());
}
```

**Login.cs:**

```
public partial class Login : Form
{
    ///......
    ///......
    private void btnIniciarSesion_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(autenticar()) // un método que devuelve verdadero cuando el usuario y la clave son correctas.
        {             
           Form_Principal formPricipal = new Form_Principal();
           this.Hide();
           formPrincipal.ShowDialog();
           this.Close();
        }
        else
        {
           MessageBox.Show("Datos Incorrectos, reintentar...");
        } 
    }
}
```

**Form_Principal.cs:**

```
public partial class Form_Principal: Form
{
    ///......
    ///......
    private void btnCerrarSesion_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       this.Hide();
       Login login = new Login();
       login.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

> De este módo al cerrar sesión, cuando intente iniciar sesión nuevamente si mostrará el formulario principal ya que el formulario se invoca directamente en el `btnIniciarSesion_Click` del `Login` pero el formulario  `Login` se quedará oculto.

Lo que necesito es que el formulario `Login` este cerrado por completo, y también poder cerrar sesión e iniciar sesión sin problemas, **¿Cómo debo hacerlo?, ¿Me pueden facilitar algunas ideas?**

> He buscado en un montón de preguntas de SO:
>
> [How can I close a login form and show the main form without my application closing?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4759407/8933039).
>
> [Mas preguntas relacionadas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/4759334?lq=1)
>
> Pero igual no logro resolver la parte de `cerrar sesión` y volver a iniciar correctamente.

Comment: No tengo mucho tiempo ahora para leer toda tu pregunta, pero creo que tienes un problema de planteamiento. Tu carga inicial siempre debe ser del formulario principal, y es éste el que debe encargarse de mostrar el formulario de login cuando corresponda (inicio de aplicación, evento de logout,etc...)

Comment: @Pikoh Me gusta tu enfoque, pero no se como implementarlo de esa manera

Comment: Es muy sencillo. Simplemente, arranca el formulario principal, y en el form_load o en el evento de pulsacion de logout, llama al form de login de forma modal con `ShowDialog`

Comment: @Pikoh Ok, cuando el usuario se autentique, entonces solo cierro el formulario login y permito que continue la carga del formulario principal, pero de este modo sigo con la confución al momento de cerrar sesión tendré que instanciar el formulario principal nuevamente y no el de inicio de sesión?

Comment: @Pikoh Lo he probado así, como te lo plantié en el comentario anterior, he colocado la invocacion del login debajo de `InitializeComponent();`, pero al cerrar sesión como ya estoy en formulario principal, este es el que debe cargar nuevamente, por tal razón hago la instancia pero nunca vuelve a entrar al evento donde se inicia el formulario principal, no se si me doy a entender

Comment: Cuando pulses el boton de cierre de sesion no tienes que hacer nada con el formulario principal. Simplemente debes volver a cargar el de login de forma modal,de esa manera el principal sigue cargado por detras.

Comment: @Pikoh y esta es una forma correcta de hacerlo en cuanto a seguridad?, ya que no se trata de un sistema para uso personal, sino con fin comercial

Comment: Es una manera sencilla de hacerlo,hay otras (podrias ir llamando de un formulario a otro y cerrar el anterior despues). En cuanto a seguridad no le veo ningun problema. Al llamar al form de login de manera modal,es imposible acceder al principal aunque le puedas ver por debajo.

Comment: @Pikoh mmm no se, no me convence esa idea, algo como esto sería ideal [Login Form](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/114370/Build-an-Application/WinForms-MVVM/Tutorials/Lesson-5-Login-Form) pero veo un montón de código aquí...

Comment: para mi, personalmente en winforms agregar lógica de negocio en el program.cs es una mala practica. por eso debes de seguir un modelo en base a un form principal, cuando tu form principal se cierre entonces tu aplicacion se cerrara. ya si quieres utilizar MDI o otra técnica, lo importante es que tu aplicación debe correr en base a tu form principal. para eso form principal debe ser estático global para toda la aplicación y no un objeto anónimo, dentro de el crearas todas las demás formas que necesites a menos que también deban ser globales a la aplicación. si quieres dejar de mostrar tu form p

Comment: Actualmente el método que estoy usando es el segundo expuesto en mi pregunta, solo hablé del método 1 porque lo vi como sugerencia de usuarios de SO, si se fija [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4759407/8933039) y en las demás preguntas relacionadas a esta, sugieren usar `Program.cs` no veo donde nadie mencione que sea una mala practica.

Comment: probablemente se usa así para matar la aplicación directamente al momento de fallar el login.
sigo sin considerarlo correcto por que desde ahi ya estas creando dos flujos distinto de trabajo, el de iniciar secion y el de re-iniciar sesion. 

me pregunto por que nadie habla entonces de la mala practica de tener un form principal anonimo : Application.Run(new Form_Principal());

Comment: No sabría decirte porque seria mal usar el _formulario principal anónimo_ como planteas. Mientras tanto sigo usando el segundo método hasta encontrar una mejor manera de hacerlo sin involucrar el **MDI**

Comment: Aprendan patrones de diseño, en este MVVM, esto no solo mejora muchísimo el codigo (hacer todo en code behind es horrible), sino que permite cosas como tener zonas dentro de una ventana donde muestras otras cosas, y quitar ese contenido y mostrar otro (navegación entee vistaa). Vale la pena que le eches una lectura a dichos patrones de diseño.

Comment: MVVM es el futuro de las aplicaciones de escritorio!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Muy buenos dias, se me ocurre una solucion a tu problema, pero cambia un poco la forma de como lo estas haciendo.  Te explico:

En programación existen los MDI, el **MDI** es un contenedor (Puedes abrir pantallas dentro de otra pantalla) y con esto podrías arreglar fácilmente tu problema.

Utilizando la propiedad isMdiContainer de los formularios tu programa quedaría algo así:

1. Creo un proyecto de Windows Forms
2. Agrego el formulario principal y lo convierto en MDI Container
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
   Automáticamente cambia el diseño del form
3. Agrego el login y hago que se inicie en cuanto se abra el sistema
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

   ```
   public partial class MDI : Form
    {
   //Guardo el usuario que inicio sesion
   public string UsuarioLogueado = "";
   public Login frmLogin;
   public PaginaPrincipal frmPrincipal;

   public MDI()
   {
       InitializeComponent();
   }

   public void AbrirFormularioPrincipal()
   {
       this.frmPrincipal = new PaginaPrincipal();
       this.frmPrincipal.MdiParent = this;
       this.frmPrincipal.Show();
   }

   public void AbrirLogin()
   {
       this.frmLogin = new Login();
       this.frmLogin.MdiParent = this;//Asigno el formulario actual como su MDI parent
       this.frmLogin.Show();
   }

   public void CerrarSesion() {
       //Solo limpio los datos del usuario
       this.UsuarioLogueado = "";
       //Muestro el login
       AbrirLogin();
   }

   private void MDI_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       //Si no hay ningun usuairo logueado muestro el login
       if(UsuarioLogueado.Trim().Length == 0)
       {
           AbrirLogin();
       }
   }
   }
   ```
4. Creo mi pagina principal para abrirla al iniciar sesión
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
5. Al iniciar sesión cierro el login y abro otra pagina de Ejemplo

LOGIN:

```
     public partial class Login : Form
{
    public Login()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(this.textBox1.Text.Trim().Length > 0)
        {
            //Asigno el usuario logueado la MDI
            ((MDI)this.MdiParent).UsuarioLogueado = this.textBox1.Text.Trim();

            //Abro el formulario principal,con una funcion del MDI parent
            ((MDI)this.MdiParent).AbrirFormularioPrincipal();

            //Cierro el formulario actual
            this.Close();

        }
    }
}
```

6. Al cerrar sesión vuelvo a mostrar el login por default

   ```
   public partial class PaginaPrincipal : Form
   {
       public PaginaPrincipal()
       {
           InitializeComponent();
       }

       private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           //Cierro la sesion desde el MDI PARENT
           ((MDI)this.MdiParent).CerrarSesion();
           //Cierro el formulario actual
           this.Close();
       }

       private void PaginaPrincipal_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           this.label1.Text = ((MDI)this.MdiParent).UsuarioLogueado;
       }
   }
   ```

Este solo es un ejemplo muy simple, puedes agregar un menú, una barra de estado, conexión a base de datos, validar si hay un usuario logueado antes de abrir una ventana, etc.

Te anexo un gif para que veas como funciona y la liga del fuente:

[Cogido fuente del ejemplo](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1T1iMZ_pHq6owLhC5IjAStxfdjzhKs8wo/view?usp=sharing)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Conozco los **MDI**, pero no puedo cambiar mi estructura actual de mi sistema para usar **MDI**, aún así gracias, es muy buen ejemplo +1.

Comment: Ok ya veo :(, entonces lo que solemos hacer es utilizar .hide(), porque me ha pasado y entras en una lógica de cerrar y abrir ventanas muy fea jejeje

Comment: Me gustaría añadir que MDI es una tecnología obsoleta, con problemas de usabilidad y que la propia Microsoft desaconseja al menos desde Windows95.

Comment: @Pikoh Windows Forms es lo obsoleto ahora todo se hace en ASP.NET, ya sea MVC o Web Forms y el NET.CORE, entre otros que no son de Microsoft, y al MDI la unica desventaja que veo es cuando tienes dos monitores al no permitirte desacoplar las pantallas, de usabilidad en mi experiencia en los años que  me toco trabajar en proyectos con MDI no recuerdo haber tenido problemas.

Comment: No era mi intención Cristina entrar en ninguna polémica. En ningun lugar he leido que windows forms esté considerado obsoleto o se desaconseje su uso,y si bien es cierto como dices que hay tecnologías mas modernas que son preferibles, windows forms es todavía usado ampliamente. Sin embargo, el patrón mdi fue desaconsejado como decía al menos desde el año 95 por la propia Microsoft, por lo que yo personalmente no aconsejaría su uso a nadie. Como digo,mi comentario no buscaba polemizar sino simplemente informar :)

Comment: @Pikoh Tampoco lo pense asi, y no sabia que estaba considerado obsoleto, es bueno saberlo, igual hace muchos años que no me ha tocado trabajar con Windows Forms, desde el punto de vista laboral actual son pocos los trabajos donde requieran Windows Form, por lo menos en Mexico

Comment: Cada vez son menos, ahora las tecnologías web y móviles son las que mandan por supuesto, pero todavía existe demanda de aplicaciones de escritorio, aunque se tiende a usar WPF en lugar de windows forms claro. Pero en España al menos aun hay demanda de ello :)